# How to create a new amazon ec2 instance with 30GB hard disk?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I think we chose option 30GB but we still got 8GB hard disk only. Where to change that?

Also after we created the launch can we still change the main hard disk size?

this is the result of df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  4.3G  3.4G  57% /
udev            288M  8.0K  288M   1% /dev
tmpfs           119M  164K  118M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            296M     0  296M   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdf        22G   11G   11G  50% /media/newdrive
```

A way to increase this without creating a new instance will also be appreciated :D

Comment: what is the instance type? Did you create a separate EBS volume and attach it?

Comment: I think I created additional ebs volume and attach it, but I like to keep databases file in default location.

Comment: what is your instance type? post your `df -h`

Comment: isntance type is ubuntu12. I know it defaults to 8GB. But I want something bigger

Comment: See here -- http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/  I don't think any instance has 8GB storage. So you could be looking at this incorrectly. If you post the df -h from the OS, it will help.

Comment: Micro Instances.

Comment: Updated :D also I upvoted all answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the size of your root disk (provided it is an EBS backed instance) as described here:
http://alestic.com/2010/02/ec2-resize-running-ebs-root
I would suggest to test this on a throw-away instance first however...

The best (and easiest) option is to give the desired space on instance launch - see the --block-device parameter on the launch call:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RunInstances.html

Answer (score 8):

Many "out of the box" linux instances from AWS have 8 GB on their primary volumes.  When launching the instance, you are givin the option increase the size of the primary volume (for example, increase it to 30 GB).

However, after the instance is launched, the filesystem on your volume is still going to report 8 GB.  This is because the volume size was increased, but the filesystem was not.  So you need to do this manually, after the fact.

Use resize2fs to resize your filesystem:

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Comment: The newer Ubuntu images instances from Canonical automatically do resize2fs on startup. So if you start your machine with the 30GB harddisk, you will instantly have the storage available after booting.

Comment: What about windows?

Comment: I use the newer ubuntu images. I think it's still using 8GB. After launching it, can I change the size?

Comment: For Windows, you would go into the Disk Management tool to increase the size of your partition to fill the entire volume.  There is also the DISKPART command line tool as well.

Comment: This is the real answer to this question (and the question itself is a good one not sure why it was downvoted or closed!)

Comment: resize2fs /dev/xvda1 >> 
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014) >> 
The filesystem is already 26212055 blocks long.  Nothing to do! >>   What is issue i dont understand